# Android RuntimeException is occurring silently and not being logged

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So I have some code that's throwing a RuntimeException. I know it's throwing a RuntimeException, I wrote it to do so under certain circumstances. Recently, I was having what I thought was a deadlock, because the method didn't seem to be finishing, but as I logged out the problem I realized that it was in fact that RuntimeException.

Now, here's the issue: This exception is occurring silently. The Android monitor in Android Studio isn't displaying a stack trace for it. This threw me off, because in normal Java applications (which I'm more used to, I'm a professional Java dev but I'm a bit new to Android), RuntimeExceptions send a stack trace directly to the console.

So, my reaction was to do a Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler to log this. Only... it's not working.

Here's my UncaughtExceptionHandler. I don't actually care about it doing all the things it does, I was just trying to get something to happen to indicate that it was being called.

```
public static class ContactsUncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler{

        private static final String TAG = "UncaughtException";

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println("UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION"); //TODO delete this
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Uncaught exception in thread %d", thread.getId()), throwable);
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

This handler is being added in the following ways:

1) I have an executor spawning threads. It uses a ThreadFactory, which assigns this handler to each thread using Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler().

2) I call Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() in the onCreate() method of my Application class.

3) The code where this is occurring is a Runnable.run() method. I put a line in that run() method calling Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler().

Nothing works. None of those operations there get triggered.

I know with 100% certainty that a RuntimeException is occurring, because if I surround the code with a try-catch block and do printStackTrace() that way, it shows up in the console log. I just can't get the UncaughtExceptionHandler to work.

The code where this is happening is very long and verbose, here's a quick summary of it:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ContactsThreadFactory.ContactsUncaughtExceptionHandler());
    System.out.println("This line outputs to the console");
    object.callingMethodThatCausesException();
    System.out.println("This line never executes, because exception was thrown");
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I don't understand why it's not working.

Edit: Just discovered something interesting, not 100% sure what it means yet. I put "throws new RuntimeException()" into the onCreate() method of my Activity class, and that exception showed up in the console like normal. I tried doing the same thing from within that Runnable, and nothing. Not entirely sure what to make of that.

Also, the UncaughtExceptionHandler worked for that new RuntimeException I put in. I just don't understand why it's not working elsewhere?